# Dynamic CRM 2015 Extension Dashboard Custom GridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dynamics-crm

I need to create ad Extension for Dynamic CRM 2015 Server where I need to create a custom Grid View in Dashboard. But online I don't find no examples...

Anyone have any tutorials or simple project good commented?

Thanks all.

Comment: I will add that although I provided an answer I'm having an internal battle in regard to the question being off-topic! Generally speaking, questions that ask for links to tutorials or sample projects are often not considered suitable for StackOverflow. Answers are as a result forced to include links which isn't in tune with the theme of the site. But what you're asking for is code related... so I'll leave my answer in place...

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to write a custom grid the first place I'd look is [Sparkle Xrm](http://www.sparklexrm.com/s/tutorials.html).

Basically it's an open source project (or soon to be) that uses Script#, jQuery & KnockoutJS that should make it easier to develop what you're looking for.